# Split in paint and new water stain, but no water source

Tags: drywall, water-damage

House was built 1.5 years ago. Just noticed this split in paint on drywall and a water stain in the garage. There’s no water source directly above, just an empty guest room. Next to the guest room, there is a bathroom, but it’s roughly 30 ft away.

Is this a concern? Any ideas of where to start diagnosing or who I should consult?

[image]

Comment: water flows mysterious ways

Comment: Water pipes in walls/ceilings?  A roof leak should be low on the list on a 1.5 year old house, but still possible.  It might also just be condensation from cold water pipe that has a low bend in it at that place.  Find if any pipes are near the stain and go from there.

Comment: check the roof plumbing vents for flashing.  i had one missing and it leaked rain water really slowly for 15 years before we figured it out....   thought it was a bathroom directly above.  is the wall of the garage a wall that goes all the way up or the room above is sitting on this wall?

Comment: Somewhere above this, there's a roof. Any roof is a water source, and water can run downhill and/or sideways a considerable distance before it appears inside the building, so the leak may not be anything like "directly above."